# Why not appear the files in submodules added into my Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, alamofire, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a problem with my Xcode project. I'm using submodules of frameworks like alamofire. I added this following the github steps... running the following command:

> $ git submodule add https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git

and then the next step like drop into project...

But my problem is then the commit and push. When I clone the project from git using sourcetree in other computer or I remove the repo and I download this, the folder of alamofire and others sdk are empty.

If I open the xcode project is red name, because haven't the files. But in my first local repository all work and if I try change to submodule in sourcetree the files are downloaded and appear.

But if I use:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/meme/myRepo.git FOLDER_NAME
```

with this command all files are downloaded.

I want get the content of those submodules when I clone my repo into a computer with sourcetree.

How can I solve this to then download the repo appear directly the sdks?

Answer (score 0):

As [illustrated in this thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-discussions/SourceTree-Submodule-updates-on-clone-pull-switch-branch/td-p/856078):

> There is a "Recurse submodules" option when cloning under "Advanced Options".

That should be enough for your original question.

However:

> nothing when pulling, checking out, or switching branched; and no manual recursive submodule update functionality.

So:

> The only way I know of updating submodules in SourceTree is to manually open each submodule (and recursively open each nested submodule) and look at the "Uncommitted changed" select only submodules that appear to have change and "Reset" the changes.